# Replace Tokens in 2 Json files with same name

Tags: json, azure-pipelines

We are using Replace tokens task in ADO pipeline in order to replace the key values which may vary in Json file.

Here in one application, we have 2 Json files with same name "appsettings.json", in the 2 Json files, we have to replace the values which are having same key name.

Eg: In one Json file(appsettings.json), key=apiurl  value=https://dev1.com
In another Json file(appsettings.json), key=apiurl  value=https://dev2.com

In the above example, how can we replace the Key values in 2 different json files with same name which are having same Key name with different value in those 2 files ?

Thanks in advance.